# How do I average values of a group range in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this Dataframe. I want to make age range 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, etc and set all values in this range by their mean.

```
    Name  Age  
0    x    5
1    y    7
2    z    2
3    p    9
4    q    12
5    r    6
6    s    5
7    t    1
8    u    13
9    v    10
```

Now I want to add a column **ageGroup** which will contain the **mean** of the required range. Here 1-5 is a range. so all of the ages between these will **mean** value. Here, (5+2+5+1) // 4 = 3. Similarly, for range 11-15 will be (12+13) // 2 = 12.

So, the expected output is.

```
    Name  Age  ageGroup
0    x    5     3
1    y    7     8
2    z    2     3
3    p    9     8
4    q    12    12
5    r    6     8
6    s    5     3
7    t    1     3
8    u    13    12
9    v    10    8
```

Comment: Clarify as to how you calculate ageGroup

Comment: This appears to be a straightforward `groupby - mean - new column` sequence.  The steps are included in any tutorial on PANDAS.  Therefore, we expect to see your code and a clear problem statement for your implementation.

Comment: The question is *how to do something* which doesnot mandate a code sample. I dont see how this is a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to bin the data and then you can use with groupby:

```
max_age = 15
step = 5
df['ageGroup'] = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Age'],
                 range(0,max_age+step,5)))['Age'].transform('mean').round()
```

---

```
print(df)

  Name  Age  ageGroup
0    x    5       3.0
1    y    7       8.0
2    z    2       3.0
3    p    9       8.0
4    q   12      12.0
5    r    6       8.0
6    s    5       3.0
7    t    1       3.0
8    u   13      12.0
9    v   10       8.0
```